# Regext for matching a listing of items separated by "," or "and"

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to match this: `first, second, third and fourth section` and get the different sections like this:

match 1: `first`

match 2: `second`

match 3: `third`

match 4: `fourth`

Also the string sections have to end with the word `section`. If it does not it should drop all matches.

How can i achieve this with regex? I have tried this so far:
https://regex101.com/r/Qwnh6m/3

`(?P<section>(first|second|third|fourth)(?=(\ssection|\sog\s(first|second|third|fourth)\ssection|,\s(first|second|third|fourth))))`

NB: It is important that the regex works on a string like this.

`something else lalala and then first, second, third and fourth section something more.`

Comment: I have tried a lot of different stuff the closes i have come is this (some of the text is in norwegian, but i hope its not important to see the example): https://regex101.com/r/Qwnh6m/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex using lookaheads:

```
\b(first|second|third|fourth)(?=,|\h+(?:and|section)\b)(?=.*\hsection\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NXVwZl/10)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b(first|second|third|fourth)` - Match 1 or more given words in the group
- `(?=` - Start a lookahead

  - `,` - Containing comma
  - `|` - OR
  - `\h+` - 1 or more horizontal white-spaces
  - `(?:` - start non-capturing group

    - `and` - containing word "**and**"
    - `|` - OR
    - `section$` - word "**section**"
  - `)` - end non-capturing group
  - `\b` - word boundary
- `)` - end lookahead
- `(?=` - start second lookahead

  - `.*section\b` - containing word "**section**"
- `)`- end second lookahead

**Edit: This was the final regex after further fixes:**
`\b(first|second|third|fourth)(?=(?:\s*(?:,|and)\s*(?:first|second|third|fourth))*\s+section\b)`

https://regex101.com/r/NXVwZl/21

Comment: This is really close, thank you! I need to just match first, second, third and fourth? is this possible? I'm trying myself right now but if this is easy for you it would be great! :)

Comment: Yes, but if you add "something" to the string like this: "first, second, something, third and fourth section" it will also match "something". I do not want this.

Comment: I want to only extract these words: "first, second, third, fourth" if they are followed by the word section in the end and only seperated by "," or "and".

Comment: ok then may be: [`\b(first|second|third|fourth)(?=,|\h+(?:and\h|section$))(?=.*\hsection$)`](https://regex101.com/r/NXVwZl/5) should work for you

Comment: Perfect i modified it a bit to allow the match to occur in the text (not just at the end). (\b(first|second|third|fourth)(?=,|\h+(?:and\h|section))(?=.*\hsection)) Thank you allot! (example https://regex101.com/r/NXVwZl/9)

Comment: I edited your answer to reflect the changes based on the comments. Hope that is ok?

Comment: Yes it is perfectly fine, let me edit description also to match with the regex to make it helpful for other readers.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry there is one last problem can you take a look at this: https://regex101.com/r/NXVwZl/15

Comment: Getting closer! :) I think it needs to somehow cancel the lookahead if it finds anythin else. Here is an updated example that fails: https://regex101.com/r/NXVwZl/17

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139484/discussion-between-anubhava-and-ole-henrik-skogstrom).